# play-json breaks sbt build

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Suddenly as of today my project has stopped compiling successfuly. Upon further investigation I've found out the reason is `play-json` library that I include in dependencies.

Here's my `build.sbt`:

```
name := """project-name"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test",
  "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk16" % "1.46",
  "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.5.1",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1101-jdbc41",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.drewnoakes" % "metadata-extractor" % "2.6.2",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.2"
)

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

If I try to create a new project in activator with all the lines except `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.2"` then it compiles successfully. But once I add `play-json` I get the folloing error:

```
[error] References to undefined settings: 
[error] 
[error]   *:playCommonClassloader from echo:run
[error] 
[error]   docs:managedClasspath from echo:run
[error] 
[error]   *:playReloaderClassloader from echo:run
[error] 
[error]   echo:playVersion from echo:echoTracePlayVersion
[error] 
[error]   *:playRunHooks from echo:playRunHooks
[error]      Did you mean echo:playRunHooks ?
[error]
```

And I keep getting this error even if I remove `play-json` line. Why is it so? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Is this play project? .If yes then add play setting in build.sbt :=>
play.Project.playScalaSettings

Comment: @Sky it's not a play project, I'm using play-json separately. But nevertheless adding `play.Project.playScalaSettings` to `build.sbt` did help. Thanks!